# Cannot work with AKAZE (OpenCV) on Java

Tags: java, opencv

I'm working on an image recognition project with Java, OpenCV and Maven. Unfortunately, I'm seeing the following error:

"java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "akaze/bin/akaze_match": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified"

The program creates that .json file in specified target; but .json file is always empty.

The related code is:

```js
private String runAkazeMatch(String object_filename, String scene_filename) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

        long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String jsonFilename = "target/keypoints/keypoints_" + timestamp + ".json";
        logger.info("Json file should be found at: {}", jsonFilename);
        File file = new File(jsonFilename);
        file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        file.createNewFile();
        System.out.println(file.getParentFile().mkdirs());
        String[] akazeMatchCommand = {"akaze/bin/akaze_match", object_filename, scene_filename, "--json", jsonFilename, "--dthreshold", "0.00000000001"};
        try {
            ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder(akazeMatchCommand);
            Process proc = p.start();
            InputStream stdin = proc.getInputStream();
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(stdin);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                System.out.print(".");
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            logger.info("Akaze matching process exited with value: " + exitVal);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            logger.error("ERROR: Image recognition with Akaze failed. No json file created.");
            return null;
        } else {
            return jsonFilename;
        }
    }
```

I've searched for this issue; and I guess it's about AKAZE on Java.
What could be the problem? And how should I work with AKAZE on Java?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that `akaze/bin/akaze_match` exsts in the _current working directory_ while running your program?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose Yes. I found the necessary files for '/akaze/' directory on Internet. But I still get same error.

Comment: I think you didn't understand what I meant: Do you have `/akaze/bin/akaze_match` or do you have `akaze/bin/akaze_match` in your _current working directory_? Do you know the _current working directory_ while running your program? It might not be what you think it is.

Comment: I understood what you meant and yes, I have **/akaze/bin/akaze_match** in my current working directory.